# Angular4 custom Structural Directive causing Component to not be found by @ContentChildren()

Tags: angular

I have 3 nested components forming a generic grid component: `MyGrid`, `MyRow`, `MyColumn` which when used take the shape below. The problem I have is that whenever I attached the `*myRowItem` directive to the `my-row` component, the component is not found by some `@ContentChildren(MyRowComponent)` located in `MyGrid`, whereas when I do not use the `*myRowItem` directive the query finds said components. It seems like the directive is obscuring the content in some way.

I know that through Angular's desugaring, the `*myRowItem` directive is translated into an `<ng-template>...</ng-template>` and sorts, but am I missing something here?

**Usage**

```
<my-grid [data-source]="dataSource">
    <my-row *myRowItem="let item">
        <my-column column-header="Person">
            {{item.name}}
        </my-column>

        <my-column column-header="Age">
            {{item.age}}
        </my-column>

        <my-column column-header="Car">
            {{item.car}}
        </my-column>
    </my-row>
</my-grid>
```

`MyGrid` is the component responsible for rendering the whole table. `MyRow` is another component which groups the columns together defined like so:

**MyRow.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-row',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
})
export class MyRowComponent 
{

  @ContentChildren(MyColumnComponent)
  public columns: QueryList<MyColumnComponent>;

  /**
   * Class constructor
   */
  constructor()
  {
  }
}
```

`MyColumn` is used to relay the template up to the grid (and has some additional functionality which I've truncated for readability purposes).

**MyColumn.ts**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-column',
   template: `<ng-container *ngIf="..."><ng-content></ng-content></ng-container>`
})
export class CoreColumnComponent
{

  ...

  constructor()
  {
  }
}
```

`*myRowItem` is used to create a context in which using `$implicit` I can pipe values to the *ngFor located in `MyGrid`.

**MyRowItem.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myRowItem]',
})
export class MyRowItemDirective
{

  constructor()
  {
  }
}
```

**MyGrid.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-grid',
  templateUrl: 'my-grid.html'
})
export class MyGridComponent implements AfterViewInit
{

   ...

  /**
   * My item directive (IS BEING POPULATED AND I CAN RENDER THROUGH IT)
   */
  @ContentChild(MyRowItemDirective, { read: TemplateRef })
  public rowTemplate: TemplateRef<MyRowItemDirective>;

  /**
 * My row component (IS NOT BEING POPULATED)
 */
  @ContentChild(MyRowComponent)
  public rowDefinition: MyRowComponent;


  constructor()
  {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void
  {
    let x = this.rowDefinitions; // BEING EMPTY HERE
  }

}
```

**MyGrid.html**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let row of dataSource" [ngTemplateOutlet]="rowTemplate" [ngOutletContext]="{$implicit: row}"></ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use setter or subscribe to changes of QueryList ? ContentChild/ContentChildren won't we populated until `createEmbeddedView` is called within your structural directive

Comment: interesting, can you create a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

The column selector in code is "core-column" which should be "my-column"?

Comment: You're right, typo when renaming items from project to example.